# MySQL JDBC: no suitable driver found

Tags: java, jdbc

I have developed a program that pulls the data from a remote sql server and pushes it to local mysql server .I have a jar file exported for this .

Now I am trying to run this jar file on different machine to do the same task .All the IP's and ports have been changed accordingly .There is no IDE on this machine .

When i am running this jar file , i get an error saying "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:/ 172 .***** "

I have installed the jdbc driver in program files .

So what do i have to do to run this jar file .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the library to the runtime classpath. A straightforward way would be to export it as a dependency in the jar (although there might be licencing issues with that).

How are you creating the jar?

Comment: Then export it with dependencies. What IDE are you using? Search around, there's bound to be an option for that. And as GerritCap said, there's no sense in putting the jdbc driver into Program Files. How did you come up with that idea in the first place..

Comment: i have added the jdbc driver in the classpath "C:\Program Files\SqlJDBC\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar" ..then also i am getting the error .

Comment: The JDBC driver isn't seen as a required library since your program doesn't use it directly. You'll need to add the library as a dependency manually.

Comment: I am using eclipse ..what are you suggesting ??

Comment: Eclipse doesn't seem to allow you to add extra dependencies by hand. I wonder how it determines the "required libraries". Of course you could always open up the jar and put the library in there manually (remember to update the manifest file for the extra lib).

Comment: Jar files are just glorified zip files. You can open 'em up with any zip-program. Then you can add the additional libs by hand. Remember to check the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jdbc driver in your classpath, not in your "program files".... Check the documentation of the JVM http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: i have added the jdbc driver in the classpath "C:\Program Files\SqlJDBC\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar" ..then also i am getting the error .

Answer (score 0):

All you need to run a Java program is a Java executable and class files or zipped/jared class files and other files needed by class files. So 1st step is locate your java executable, maybe c:\java.exe or /home/yourhome/java, and 2nd step is gather all your classes or zip/jar archive and put them in a String split by ':' on Unix or Unix-like or ';' on windows. 3rd step is to identify your main class, which is the only entry of your program.

In the end, use YOUR_JAVA_EXECYTABLE -classpath YOUR_CLASS_PATH YOUR_MAIN_CLASS. works fine for most scenarios.

Forget anything about "installed" a program or driver, which is just put some some in system's classpath or path or anything like this.